# LIMIT on the right part of a jointure

Tags: mysql, sql, join, limit

I have two SQL tables :

```
collections(id, user_id, name)
files(id, collection_id, name, start_date)
```

And I would like, with one request, to retrieve every collections of a given user with a "preview" of 3 files (maximum) per collection.

My first (and only) thought was something like this :

```
SELECT f.*
    FROM collections c 
    LEFT JOIN files f
    ON f.collection_id = c.id
    WHERE c.user_id = 1 AND f.id IN
        (
            SELECT id
                FROM files
                WHERE collection_id = c.id
                ORDER BY start_date DESC
                LIMIT 3
        )
    ORDER BY c.name, f.start_date DESC
```

But it doesn't work with MySQL, giving :

```
#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

Do you have an idea? =/

Thanks.

Comment: Could you give a sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a little trick that makes use of GROUP_CONCAT and FIND_IN_SET, like this:

```
SELECT
  f.*
FROM
  collections c INNER JOIN files f
  ON c.id = f.collection_id
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      collection_id, GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY start_date DESC) ids
    FROM
      files
    GROUP BY
      collection_id) cf
  ON f.collection_id = cf.collection_id
     AND FIND_IN_SET(f.id, cf.ids)<=3
WHERE c.user_id = 1
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e2c6/1). It won't be very fast, but if you just need to return a few records it should be okay.

Or you could use this query:

```
SELECT
  f.*
FROM
  collections c INNER JOIN files f
  ON c.id = f.collection_id
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT f.collection_id, f.id
    FROM
      files f LEFT JOIN files f2
      ON f.collection_id = f2.collection_id
         AND (f.start_date < f2.start_date
              OR ((f.start_date = f2.start_date) AND (f.id<f2.id)))
    GROUP BY
      f.id
    HAVING
      COUNT(f2.id)<3
    ) last_three
  ON f.collection_id = last_three.collection_id
     AND f.id = last_three.id
```

Comment: It looks heavy, but I can't find something else :)
Thanks, I'll use it!

Comment: @Tiller i've just updated my answer, or you can see this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fc28/16 the problem here is that more than one record share the same start_date with others, so I had to add an extra condition on the join, in case there are more than one record that share the same start_date then we have to keep the ones that have an higher id

Comment: Thanks! That fine. I just changed a little bit your query to: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2b3d/3 to retrieve also collection having no files. Is it good enough? :)

Comment: @Tiller yep you need a left join in that case :) it looks good, i hope it's okay :)

Answer (score 0):

Innern join only returns row they match on both tables.

So just set the limit at the end of the main query.

```
SELECT f.*
    FROM collections c 
    JOIN files f
    ON f.collection_id = c.id
   INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT id
                FROM files
                WHERE collection_id = c.id
                ORDER BY start_date DESC
        ) ff ON f.id=ff.id  WHERE c.user_id = 1 
    ORDER BY c.name, f.start_date DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: And if I'm using the latest MySQL version? I open a ticket on mysql tracker? :)

Comment: Which version do you use?

Comment: 5.6.12
But anyway, I need something which works on a "large" scale of version :)

Comment: Sorry. Had a confusing...   Edited my answer and this should work ^^

Comment: If I set the limit at the end of the query, I'll have 3 overall results, even if I have 4 collections. That's not what I want.

Comment: I don't know how the tabke structur is but when you remove all limits, does it then shows you your wished result?